# Android listview item filter issue

Tags: android, database, listview, filter

I have a `ListView` which work fine. Now I have put an `EditText` at the top of my `ListView`. What I want is that when a enters a letter "A", only the names starting with an "A" should appear in the list . I have try to do this but nothing happen please check my code and tell me where I doing wrong.

This is my code of data list.

```
public class DataListActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    FoodDbHelper foodDbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
    private Button button1;
    ListDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    Button button;
    DataProvider dataProvider;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> namessList;
    EditText inputSearch;
    String search_name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);







    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(DataListActivity.this, button1);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater()
                        .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DataListActivity.this);
                        a_builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Close This App !!!")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        //finish();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                        alert.setTitle("Alert !!!");
                        alert.show();
                        // Toast.makeText(
                        //   MainMenu.this,
                        //   "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                        //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        // ).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show(); //showing popup menu
            }
        });








        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_View);

        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.row_layout) {




            @Override
            protected void showCheckedButton(int position, boolean value) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DataProvider item = (DataProvider) listDataAdapter
                        .getItem(position);
                Log.i("", "");

                item.setSelected(value);

                Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                        responseText
                               .append("The following dishes were selected...\n");

                        ArrayList<DataProvider> list = listDataAdapter
                                .getSelectedIndexes();

                        int sum = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            DataProvider dataProvider = list.get(i);

                            sum = sum + dataProvider.getCalorie();

                            responseText.append("\n" + dataProvider.getName()
                                    + " : " + dataProvider.getCalorie()
                                    + " kcal"
                                    );

                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+responseText+"\n"+"................................."
                                       +"\n"+"Total Calories In Your Menu Is : " +sum,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });



                inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

                listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
                inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // When user changes the Text
                        listDataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                  int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

            }





        };
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = foodDbHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name, quantity, fat, protein, sugar, vitamins;
                boolean selected = false;
                String names = null;
                Integer calorie;

                name = cursor.getString(0);
                quantity = cursor.getString(1);
                calorie = Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(2));
                fat = cursor.getString(3);
                protein = cursor.getString(4);
                sugar = cursor.getString(5);
                vitamins = cursor.getString(6);

                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name, quantity,
                        calorie, fat, protein, sugar, vitamins, names, selected);

                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());


        }





        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                String name = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_dish_name)).getText();
                String quantity = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_dish_quantity)).getText();
                String calorie = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_dish_calorie)).getText();
                String fat = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_dish_fat)).getText();
                String protein = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_dish_protein)).getText();
                String sugar = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_dish_sugar)).getText();
                String vitamins = (String) ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_dish_vitamins)).getText();

                String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "dish name is : " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Detail.class);
                intent.putExtra("Dish name", name);
                intent.putExtra("Dish quantity", quantity);
                intent.putExtra("Dish calorie", calorie);
                intent.putExtra("Dish fat", fat);
                intent.putExtra("Dish protein", protein);
                intent.putExtra("Dish sugar", sugar);

                intent.putExtra("Dish vitamins", vitamins);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
    }

    public void gobackk(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);` appears twice in your code. This might be the problem. Otherwise put some debug output in the text change listener and see if it gets called. "Nothing happens" is generally too little information for others to help you solve your problem.

Comment: how to putt debug output in the text change listener